# Why would a PTR record be ignored?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

Why would a single domain controller ignore a valid PTR record which has successfully synced to it in an AD Integrated reverse lookup zone?

I am running:

```
nslookup <hostIP> <dnsserver>
```

And find nothing. Running the same command against another DC works fine. I have connected to each DC and the PTR record exists in all of them.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, but it may be a cached NXDOMAIN on the DC for the PTR record in question. Try flushing the DNS client cache on the DC and see if that works (ipconfig/flushdns).

Comment: If that doesn't do the trick then run nslookup in debug mode (set debug) and try the query again. Debug mode will give you more information on the query and answer that might give you a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: Do other records in the same zone work?

Comment: I will try debug mode tomorrow thanks, yes other records in the same zone work, I have not been able to determine any difference between the working ones and non-working ones. But they all work when queried against a different DC.

Comment: Perhaps check the security permissions on the record?  If they became corrupt somehow it might cause the record to be ignored.  Also check the event log on the DC (especially but not only the DNS server event log) for any signs of trouble.